# Wirecloud FIWARE Lab NGSI HTTP proxy is alive

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm creating a Wirecloud Mashup using ngsi-source operator. 
Until some days ago everything worked very well but from yesterday the NGSI Proxy `http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` seems not be alive.
There are some issues with this service.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

> **Update**
>
> `ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` is up and running again :).

No, the NGSI Proxy is currently not working. We have reported it to the technical team but we have not received yet an answer so we don't have an estimation about when it will be fixed.

We have deployed a temporal instance of the NGSI proxy at the following URL: `https://mashup.lab.fiware.org:8443`

This instance will be removed once restored the service at `https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org`

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Have you deployed a temporal instance of NGSI Proxy with **http** Protocol?

Comment: Sorry, we didn't deploy a temporal instance of the NGSI proxy supporting the **http** protocol, but we restored the `ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` machine. It supports both protocols: http and https :). Use `http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` as URL.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.